# Is it ok for my reputation to be edit-based?

Tags: discussion, editing, reputation

In [this post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15434/should-i-edit-posts-to-improve-clarity) I asked whether I should continue barraging my peers with edits.  I still have one question, though.  I've made around 20% of my reputation off of edits.  Is this honest, or should I cut back a bit?  Reputation is *supposed* to be a measure of how much the community trusts me, but it seems that my reputation in this case is partially based off of grammatical skill rather than knowledge of Ubuntu.

Comment: As an aside: if you improve many posts that remain inherently bad (despite your good edit) you will loose some of those points again when those post get deleted eventually. (e.g. https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/572500 seems to be such a case where your efforts could be better spent elsewhere)

Comment: Thank you for the intelligence, officer.  Seriously, that's a good point, and I hadn't thought of it.  I guess it would have been better on the reviewers' time as well for me to have left that one alone, eh?

Comment: No worries, I didn't mean to criticize but I lively remember my disappointment when I "suddenly" lost almost 100 points in the course of 2 months.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, it is totally fine.

Besides, reputation from edits are capped at 1000. So after your 500th edit suggestions, you will stop getting reputation.

Also you do not get reputation from edits, but from "approved edit suggestions". Knowing this, when you reach 2k rep, you will no longer be able to suggest edits on posts, instead you will be able to edit them without waiting for someone to review them. This will stop you from receiving the 2 rep per edit suggestion.

However you would still be able to receive 2 rep from edit suggestion on tag wikis until 20k.

Comment: I guess that means I'm best off to get all the approved edit suggestions rep while I can, eh?

Comment: @anonymous2 Well, to be honest, I don't think should worry about that. "Whichever comes first." You shouldn't stop posting answers or asking questions just so you can get the full 1k rep from edit suggestions.

Comment: That makes sense.  I didn't really mean it that way...  In any case if I was just aiming to go up as fast as possible, edits are certainly not the fastest way to do it...

Comment: @anonymous2 - I'm not sure but I think you can get editing reputation above 1000 rep, but you don't edits approved at 2000 https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: I guess I'll know soon... :)

Answer (score 21):

Well the community needs your grammatical skill as much as it needs a knowledge of Ubuntu.

Good question and answers are no use if no one can understand them.

Answer (score 13):

Trust isn't only about knowledge of Ubuntu. It's also about being a helpful person who has the community's best interest at heart. So the reputation you gain from editing is well deserved. That said, the 1000 cap is correct.

Answer (score 13):

Just to add another way of saying it:

The longer you are on this site, the more you realize that *good questions* are the key to a better quality of the site. Good questions are clear about what to answer and ***invoke*** good and clear answers.

If you play a role in improving the quality of questions (and answers), you are doing a job of major importance, and deserve the reputation you earned with it.